# Selenium can't start test WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

i have problem with run protractor test on linux ubuntu, the browser doesn't open (google chrome) to run test i use command
protractor ./config.js

i got error

```
[22:04:01] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[22:04:01] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[22:05:01] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.13.0-38-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.06 seconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'maciek', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[22:05:01] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.13.0-38-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.06 seconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'maciek', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at WebDriverError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[22:05:01] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I using webdriver-manager: 
consol log

```
[18:58:53] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.37 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.20.1 -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -port 4444
[18:58:53] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 17729
18:58:54.153 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'
18:58:54.154 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-04-09 18:58:54.223:INFO::main: Logging initialized @250ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
18:58:54.339 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Welcome to Selenium for Workgroups....
18:58:54.340 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
18:58:59.229 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, chromeOptions: {}, count: 1}
18:58:59.230 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7) on port 16779
Only local connections are allowed
```

the command webdriver-manager status

```
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[22:08:53] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.11.0 [last]
[22:08:53] I/status - chromedriver versions available: 2.36, 2.37 [last]
[22:08:53] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.20.1 [last]
[22:08:53] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[22:08:53] I/status - appium is not present
```

and java --version

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

google chrome version:
version 65.0.3325.181 (64-bit)

i change computer and  i didn't have problem before( before i use linux mint now i have linux ubuntu).

It is angular app starting on docker

my config.js looking that

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['e2e/myTest'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
     args: ['--no-sandbox']
   }
  },
  chromeOnly: true,
};
```

in console webdriver-manager any errors

any idea what i can do?

Comment: Ensure that you are executing the test as a non-root user.

Comment: I'm tried using root and non-root account, the same result i had.

Comment: Please try again with ChromeDriver 2.40. I have noticed ChromeDriver 2.37 was not working.

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem 
when i start webdriver-manager using command

```
webdriver-manager start --detach
```

i don't have any errors

Comment: This command is works for me. Thank you so much for saving my time.

Answer (score 0):

you are having two chrome driver with different versions installed. May be you can try uninstalling the old one. 
Also you no need to provide the chromeOnly flag.

Make sure there is no symlink pointed to different folders.

Comment: In my older computer i have 3 version chrome driver, and It wasn't problem. but i tried and the same result.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Is anything happened after that

Comment: Webdriver-manager maintains a list of previous versions installed. It will use the last version downloaded if the version is not specified. There is no symlinking in webdriver-manager. If you need to remove the binaries, `webdriver-manager clean` should wipe the directory.